# stacking data from two tables with different dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, `Sales` and `Returns`. They have CustomerID, ProductCode, Name, SalesDate, SalesWeek, SalesAmount and ReturnsDate, ReturnsWeek, ReturnsAmount. What I really want to do is just join these tables and stack them on top of each other so the client has data in a single report for both sales and returns.

Sales and Returns dates are different but the product code, customer ID and Name can be same for a record in output table. For instance Customer A bought a product last month and returned it next month, so his record can appear in returns table.

To achieve this I have tried using union by selecting all columns between both tables but I am getting a mix of records for sales and returns with no consistency. All I want to do is see Nulls for Customers who have no business with Returns and vice versa. I was thinking Left Join in this case should work but it isn't working. So I am seeing mixed up data in all columns for Sales and Returns amounts. Attached is the picture that has two tables, the output I am seeing and the out put I want to see. Also I am performing Weekly aggregations for Sales and Returns amounts. What is the best and easiest way to achieve this ? I am sorry I may have not structured my question properly but the image might help #NewToSQL

[image]

Comment: Presumably a customer can purchase a given product more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, a customer can purchase a given product more than once.  If so, a `full join` is the right solution, but you need a bit more logic to ensure non-duplication in the results:

```
select . . .
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product_code, customer_id order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from sales s
     ) s full join
     (select r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by product_code, customer_id order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from returns r
     ) r
     on s.product_code = r.product_code and s.customer_id = r.customer_id;
```

I am leaving the name out, because I assume it is defined by the customer id.

Comment: while I understand the logic you have provided I want to stress on the fact that the product Code from both tables are different, for instance, I want to see all Sales Product Codes and they may be present in Returns, may not be. So in select how do I select all product codes from both tables into one column on output?

Comment: How can I use the above logic but use both the Columns (product code from sales and returns) from two tables to output into the report ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a FULL JOIN sales table with returns table on those columns that you mentioned.

Something like :

```
SELECT *
FROM sales s
FULL JOIN returns r
ON s.product_code = r.product_code
AND s.customerid = r.customer_id
```